# Do tuples obscure values and parameters as indexes?

Tags: java, functional-programming

### Learning About Functional Programming

I'm learning about functional programming. I decide to try it out in Java using tuples.

I read Sajal Chakraborty's [Java tuple – Working with tuples in Java](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/basics/java-tuples/) and decided to create a few examples. Java doesn't innately include tuple functionality. So I installed the [javatuples](https://www.javatuples.org/) library.

### Benefits of Functional Programming

The benefits of functional programming are hard to argue with.

- Immutable objects that aren't modified as they are passed around the system—better concurrency and parallelism¹.
- Faster prototyping/more concise—no need to create bloated boilerplate filled POJOs².
- No side effects—functions output depend on input³.
- Simple and easy unit testing—no need to worry about calling functions in a certain order or setting up external state⁴.

In fact, Erik Meijer in his edX course [Introduction to Functional Programming](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-functional-programming-delftx-fp101x-0) argues that functional programming "allows programs to be written clearly, concisely, and at a high-level of abstraction".

However, I'm struggling with the index based nature of tuples. They don't seem clearer to me.

### GPS Coordinates Example

Take for example a fictitious application that accepts and saves GPS coordinates.

#### Object Oriented Version

Following the Object Oriented Programming (OOP) paradigm, you would create a Java object.

```
public class Coordinates {
  private Double lat;
  private Double lng;

  public Coordinates(Double lat, Double lng) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
  }

  public Double getLat() {
    return lat;
  }

  public Double getLng() {
    return lng;
  }
}
```

Then you would create a service to save the coordinates.

```
public class CoordinatesService {

  public static void saveCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates) {
    double latitude = coordinates.getLat();
    double longitude = coordinates.getLng();

        // Save the coordinates (before they are lost forever! ;))
  }
}
```

And finally, you would create new coordinates and pass them to the service.

```
Coordinates coordinatesWithPojo = new Coordinates(34.90011, 46.62922);
CoordinatesService.saveCoordinates(coordinatesWithPojo);
```

#### Functional Programming Version

Following the functional programming paradigm (using tuples), you would create a service to save the coordinates.

```
public class CoordinatesService {

  public static void saveCoordinates(Pair<Double, Double> coordinates) {
    double latitude = coordinates.getValue0();
    double longitude = coordinates.getValue1();

        // Save the coordinates (before they are lost forever! ;))
  }
}
```

And then you would create the new coordinates and pass them to the service.

```
Pair<Double, Double> coordinatesWithTuple = Pair.with(34.90011, 46.62922);
CoordinatesService.saveCoordinates(coordinatesWithTuple);
```

### Obscurity Tradeoff?

While the functional version is more concise, the OOP version seems more clear. When accessing the `Coordinates` object in [IntelliJ IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), it's clear what the `Coordinates` object is made up of.

[image]

However, when I access the fields in the tuple, they are obscured by indexes.

[image]

It's hard to know which index is associated with latitude and with longitude. And what happens if they accidentally get switched? This is a simple example. But this problem grows as the number of parameters in the tuple increases.

Even the parameter annotations are clearer in the OOP version.

**OOP Version**

[image]

**Functional Version**

[image]

### Questions

- Is the fact that Java tuples create obscurity a tradeoff of adhering to the functional programming paradigm?
- Is this a general tradeoff of functional programming?
- If this is true, isn't it the opposite of a good abstraction—creating clear and concise language and meaning that humans understand and can reason about?

**Note:** I have an elementary knowledge of functional programming. This means I'm still learning how to frame my questions and arguments about the subject. As such, I'll gladly accept any feedback on the questions themselves. My goal is to learn more about functional programming—not get into a heated argument.

---

#### Sources

¹[Java 8 in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/java-8-in-action)
²[Introduction to Functional Programming](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-functional-programming-delftx-fp101x-0)
³[Functional Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/functional.html)
⁴[Functional Programming For The Rest of Us](https://www.defmacro.org/2006/06/19/fp.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pair` (or `Tuple`) are anonymous, indexed as you said. However *functional programming* would call the following *functional* too:

```
public class Coordinates {
  public final double lat;
  public final double lng;

  public Coordinates(double lat, double lng) {
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lng = lng;
  }

  public Coordinates translate(double dlat, double dlng) {
      return new Coordinates(..., ...);
  }
}

BiFunction<Coordinates, Coordinates, Coordinates> f = Coordinates::translate;
Coordinates c1 = f.apply(c2, c3);
```

This version of Coordinates is *immutable* (final fields), and hence suited as FOP class.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very relevant and i had to face that type of problems when i wanted to use FP in java.
First, there is no Functionnal programming in java, since Java does not satisfies the FP paradigme conditions.

eg.
the first citizen in java is the object and not the function

there is no high order function, hence the methods belongs to a class

it's no possible to currify on java, the poor alternative is to call a chain of methods but is nothing like myFunction(p1)(p2)(p3)

If you want to train and/or use FP i recommend to use a language which has the FP paradigm like Javascript, Kotlin Scala or Haskell.

sorry for my poor english, i hope it will help